# Ubuntu 16.10 - new possibilities from desktop to IoT. Can someone explain what is making this version so special to IoT solutions?

Tags: 16.10

Today I went to Ubuntu website and saw the new version Ubuntu 16.10 that claims to be related to IoT development.

After passing some minutes over the website I could not find the reason of the claim. I was expecting to find some basic software by default already installed like Node-red or others. Even if it is not important, because we can install them trough apt-get, when needed.

So, only by curiosity, why are this new version claiming to be the one to work with IoT?

Answer (score 0):

See this article for information:
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/10/13/canonical-releases-ubuntu-16-10/

Snap packages are able to be packaged for many platforms, embedded systems included. MAAS 2.0 allows better server deployment, etc.